# Fancybox shows blob as string not image (Ruby issue?)

Tags: ruby, string, image, fancybox, blob

I am displaying an image obtained from a database (stored as a long blob) in an `img` tag using the following method:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/show_image/265" />
```

The show_image function takes the image data from the database and renders it to the `img` tag   using the `send_data` method.

When applying Fancybox onto the `img` tag, the data is displayed as BLOB data not the image..

Can anyone suggest a reason why? Or how I can solve this?

Comment: What headers/content attributes are you sending with the streamed blob (Content-type etc)?

Comment: `send_data (@image, :type => "jpg",
                 :filename => @image.filename,
                 :disposition => 'inline')`

Comment: How do you bind the image to fancybox? ... where is your javascript code?

Comment: I bind it like this: <a class="fancybox" href="localhost:3000/show_image_small/265"><img src="localhost:3000/show_image/265" /></a>

Comment: setting :type => "image/jpg" fixed the issue. I looked up the MIME content types and realised it was incorrectly written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting :type => "image/jpg" fixed the issue. I looked up the MIME content types and realised it was incorrectly written.

Comment: Where did u set this content type?

Comment: In the controller, within the `send_data` function, you can pass the hash there. Example: `send_data(data, :type => "image/jpeg",
           :filename => imageData.id.to_s+".jpg",
           :disposition => 'inline')`

Comment: I solved my issue but creating two getimage.php files , one for image on page and one for fancy box.. and it works

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to apply fancyBox to the links (not the images) and the structure should be like this -

`<a class="fancybox" href="big_image"><img src="small_image" /></a>`

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/CYCeM/.

Well, it is actually possible to have only images, but then you have to use "data-fancybox-href" attribute to specify the large one - http://jsfiddle.net/6ZSWB/

2) Looks like the script would not be able to guess the content type from your hrefs. You have to either -

a) Create links having extension, e.g., "http://localhost:3000/show_image/265.jpg"

b) Set content type for fancybox, example - `$('.fancybox').fancybox(type : 'image');`